# Use SQL to create and populate columns based on values from query

Tags: sql, postgresql, transform

Is there a way, and I'm sure there is, with SQL to take results from one SQL statement to return results with only the MAX(date) row returned with columns populated with dates found/based on values from the original SQL statement?

The corresponding date fields (dttm) should be populated with the first date where the bug_id satisfies the condition, i.e. in the example below, based on how much data we store in the backlog, backlog would be 2019-01-09 (we only store about 2 years of data in our datalake), and verified would be 2019-01-14.

Ideally we would use the defect_*_day_flag TRUE|FALSE values in this scenario since these columns are populated by existing ETL code that flag the values according to predefined definitions of what it means to be backlog v. resolved etc.

For example, I have a table/view similar to the following that I would like to use as my "input" or source:

```
phase_date  bug_id  creation_dttm   severity    status  defect_regression_day_flag  defect_reopen_day_flag  defect_backlog_day_flag defect_resolution_day_flag  defect_rejected_day_flag    defect_verified_day_flag    defect_failedtest_day_flag
2019-01-09  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  NEW        FALSE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-10  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  NEW        FALSE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-11  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  ASSIGNED    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-12  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  IN PROGRESS FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-13  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  IN PROGRESS FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2019-01-14  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  VERIFIED    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
2019-01-15  113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  CLOSED  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

To generate the following

```
bug_id  creation_dttm   severity    status  regression_dttm reopen_dttm backlog_dttm    resolution_dttm rejected_dttm   verified_dttm   failed_test_dttm
113998  2004-01-21 3:15:24  medium  CLOSED         NULL          NULL   2019-01-09         2019-01-15       NULL          2019-02-14        NULL
```

Note that this is not the only bug in the system, there are thousands, this is only a one bug sample.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: This is a JBoss Data Virtualization view based on teiid.  Typically sql that works for postrgresql will typically work here.